# Subset a List of Files between Two Strings in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a list of files in a similar pattern to below:

```
filenames <- c("MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950120.SUB.nc",
               "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950121.SUB.nc",
               "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950122.SUB.nc",
               "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950123.SUB.nc",
               "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950124.SUB.nc",
               "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950125.SUB.nc",
               "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950126.SUB.nc",
               "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950127.SUB.nc",
               "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950128.SUB.nc",
               "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950129.SUB.nc")
```

I would like to extract each file between two dates (specified by the numbers after the "Nx.".

For example, I would like a subset of January 20th, 1995 - January 23rd, 1995. I would like another subset of January 22nd, 1995 - January 25th, 1995, and so on. I will be conducting individual analyses on each one of these "mini-datasets".

I have tried to work with the "stringr" package, but no luck. The closest I've gotten was using the `str_subset(x, "[a-u]")` expression (except with the filenames in place of the "a" and "u"), but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following, which is:

- Define the range for your dates you want to extract
- get the date information out of your filenames
- Filter on those dates defined by your range

---

```
library(tidyverse)
date_start <- as.Date('01-20-1995', format = '%m-%d-%Y')

date_end <- as.Date('01-23-1995', format = '%m-%d-%Y')

match_dates <- seq(date_start, date_end, by = 'day')

filenames_subset <- as.data.frame(filenames) %>%
  mutate(date = str_match(filenames, 'Nx.(.*?).SUB')[,2],
         date = as.Date(date, format = '%Y%m%d')) %>%
  filter(date %in% !!match_dates) %>%
  pull(filenames)

[1] "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950120.SUB.nc"
[2] "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950121.SUB.nc"
[3] "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950122.SUB.nc"
[4] "MERRA2_200.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19950123.SUB.nc"
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the following which yields the same result:

```
date_start <- as.Date('19950120', format = '%Y%m%d')

date_end <- as.Date('19950123', format = '%Y%m%d')

match_dates <- format(seq(date_start, date_end, by = 'day'), '%Y%m%d')

stringr::str_subset(filenames, paste0(match_dates, collapse = '|'))
```